# How can I scan barcodes on iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, cocoa-touch, barcode

How can I simply scan barcodes on iPhone and/or iPad?

Comment: Sadly, the iPhone camera is currently terrible for reading barcodes as  it's lens is fixed focus to ∞. Best of luck though!

Comment: Just have been solving this problem so will write my observations. I tested few options. RSBarcodes_Swift - was easy to integrate, but had very poor performance. ZBarSDK - was also easy to implement, altho took few google searched to find how. But had really good performance (did not scan datamatrix and other rare codes) works really well for barcodes/QRCode. But Scandit was the best of them all. Super fast, scans everything. sadly costs quite a lot.

Answer (score 84, accepted):

We produced the 'Barcodes' application for the iPhone. It can decode QR Codes. The source code is available from the [zxing project](http://code.google.com/p/zxing); specifically, you want to take a look at the [iPhone client](http://code.google.com/p/zxing/source/browse/#svn/trunk/iphone) and the [partial C++ port of the core library](http://code.google.com/p/zxing/source/browse/#svn/trunk/cpp). The port is a little old, from circa the 0.9 release of the Java code, but should still work reasonably well.

If you need to scan other formats, like 1D formats, you could continue the port of the Java code within this project to C++.

EDIT: Barcodes and the `iphone` code in the project were retired around the start of 2014.

Answer (score 57):

As with the release of `iOS7` you no longer need to use an external framework or library. **The iOS ecosystem with AVFoundation now fully supports scanning** almost every code from QR over EAN to UPC.

Just have a look at the [Tech Note](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2325/_index.html) and the AVFoundation programming guide. `AVMetadataObjectTypeQRCode` is your friend.

Here is a nice **tutorial** which shows it step by step:
[iPhone QR code scan library iOS7](http://www.ama-dev.com/iphone-qr-code-library-ios-7/)

Just a little example on how to set it up:

```
#pragma mark -
#pragma mark AVFoundationScanSetup

- (void) setupScanner;
{
    self.device = [AVCaptureDevice defaultDeviceWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];

    self.input = [AVCaptureDeviceInput deviceInputWithDevice:self.device error:nil];

    self.session = [[AVCaptureSession alloc] init];

    self.output = [[AVCaptureMetadataOutput alloc] init];
    [self.session addOutput:self.output];
    [self.session addInput:self.input];

    [self.output setMetadataObjectsDelegate:self queue:dispatch_get_main_queue()];
    self.output.metadataObjectTypes = @[AVMetadataObjectTypeQRCode];

    self.preview = [AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer layerWithSession:self.session];
    self.preview.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill;
    self.preview.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height);

    AVCaptureConnection *con = self.preview.connection;

    con.videoOrientation = AVCaptureVideoOrientationLandscapeLeft;

    [self.view.layer insertSublayer:self.preview atIndex:0];
}
```

Comment: I found i had to call `startRunning` on the session to get the above code to work in case that helps anyone :)

Answer (score 10):

There are two major libraries:

- [ZXing](http://code.google.com/p/zxing/) a library written in Java and then ported to Objective C / C++ (QR code only). And an other port to ObjC has been done, by TheLevelUp: [ZXingObjC](https://github.com/TheLevelUp/ZXingObjC)
- [ZBar](http://zbar.sourceforge.net) an open source software for reading bar codes, C based.

According to my experiments, **ZBar is far more accurate and fast** than ZXing, at least on iPhone.

Comment: Seems to me like ZXingObjC is the one that should be pushed to the top with the most votes by now.  I haven't used it *yet*, but the description says it's on parity with ZXing 2.0.

Comment: ZBar license requires you to offer the object files to the users, so they could run it and may modify their library as well.

Answer (score 7):

You can find another native iOS solution using **Swift 4** and **Xcode 9** at below. Native `AVFoundation` framework used with in this solution.

First part is the a subclass of `UIViewController` which have related setup and handler functions for `AVCaptureSession`.

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation

class BarCodeScannerViewController: UIViewController {

    let captureSession = AVCaptureSession()
    var videoPreviewLayer: AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer!
    var initialized = false

    let barCodeTypes = [AVMetadataObject.ObjectType.upce,
                        AVMetadataObject.ObjectType.code39,
                        AVMetadataObject.ObjectType.code39Mod43,
                        AVMetadataObject.ObjectType.code93,
                        AVMetadataObject.ObjectType.code128,
                        AVMetadataObject.ObjectType.ean8,
                        AVMetadataObject.ObjectType.ean13,
                        AVMetadataObject.ObjectType.aztec,
                        AVMetadataObject.ObjectType.pdf417,
                        AVMetadataObject.ObjectType.itf14,
                        AVMetadataObject.ObjectType.dataMatrix,
                        AVMetadataObject.ObjectType.interleaved2of5,
                        AVMetadataObject.ObjectType.qr]

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        setupCapture()
        // set observer for UIApplicationWillEnterForeground, so we know when to start the capture session again
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self,
                                           selector: #selector(willEnterForeground),
                                           name: .UIApplicationWillEnterForeground,
                                           object: nil)
    }

    override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
        // this view is no longer topmost in the app, so we don't need a callback if we return to the app.
        NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self,
                                              name: .UIApplicationWillEnterForeground,
                                              object: nil)
    }

    // This is called when we return from another app to the scanner view
    @objc func willEnterForeground() {
        setupCapture()
    }

    func setupCapture() {
        var success = false
        var accessDenied = false
        var accessRequested = false

        let authorizationStatus = AVCaptureDevice.authorizationStatus(for: .video)
        if authorizationStatus == .notDetermined {
            // permission dialog not yet presented, request authorization
            accessRequested = true
            AVCaptureDevice.requestAccess(for: .video,
                                      completionHandler: { (granted:Bool) -> Void in
                                          self.setupCapture();
            })
            return
        }
        if authorizationStatus == .restricted || authorizationStatus == .denied {
            accessDenied = true
        }
        if initialized {
            success = true
        } else {
            let deviceDiscoverySession = AVCaptureDevice.DiscoverySession(deviceTypes: [.builtInWideAngleCamera,
                                                                                        .builtInTelephotoCamera,
                                                                                        .builtInDualCamera],
                                                                          mediaType: .video,
                                                                          position: .unspecified)

            if let captureDevice = deviceDiscoverySession.devices.first {
                do {
                    let videoInput = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: captureDevice)
                    captureSession.addInput(videoInput)
                    success = true
                } catch {
                    NSLog("Cannot construct capture device input")
                }
            } else {
                NSLog("Cannot get capture device")
            }
        }
        if success {
            DispatchQueue.global().async {
                self.captureSession.startRunning()
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    let captureMetadataOutput = AVCaptureMetadataOutput()
                    self.captureSession.addOutput(captureMetadataOutput)
                    let newSerialQueue = DispatchQueue(label: "barCodeScannerQueue") // in iOS 11 you can use main queue
                    captureMetadataOutput.setMetadataObjectsDelegate(self, queue: newSerialQueue)
                    captureMetadataOutput.metadataObjectTypes = self.barCodeTypes
                    self.videoPreviewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: self.captureSession)
                    self.videoPreviewLayer.videoGravity = .resizeAspectFill
                    self.videoPreviewLayer.frame = self.view.layer.bounds
                    self.view.layer.addSublayer(self.videoPreviewLayer)
                } 
            }
            initialized = true
        } else {
            // Only show a dialog if we have not just asked the user for permission to use the camera.  Asking permission
            // sends its own dialog to th user
            if !accessRequested {
                // Generic message if we cannot figure out why we cannot establish a camera session
                var message = "Cannot access camera to scan bar codes"
                #if (arch(i386) || arch(x86_64)) && (!os(macOS))
                    message = "You are running on the simulator, which does not hae a camera device.  Try this on a real iOS device."
                #endif
                if accessDenied {
                    message = "You have denied this app permission to access to the camera.  Please go to settings and enable camera access permission to be able to scan bar codes"
                }
                let alertPrompt = UIAlertController(title: "Cannot access camera", message: message, preferredStyle: .alert)
                let confirmAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: { (action) -> Void in
                    self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
                })
                alertPrompt.addAction(confirmAction)
                self.present(alertPrompt, animated: true, completion: nil)
            }
        }
    }

    func handleCapturedOutput(metadataObjects: [AVMetadataObject]) {
        if metadataObjects.count == 0 {
            return
        }

        guard let metadataObject = metadataObjects.first as? AVMetadataMachineReadableCodeObject else {
            return
        }

        if barCodeTypes.contains(metadataObject.type) {
            if let metaDataString = metadataObject.stringValue {
                captureSession.stopRunning()
                displayResult(code: metaDataString)
                return
            }
        }
    }

    func displayResult(code: String) {
        let alertPrompt = UIAlertController(title: "Bar code detected", message: code, preferredStyle: .alert)
        if let url = URL(string: code) {
            let confirmAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Launch URL", style: .default, handler: { (action) -> Void in
                UIApplication.shared.open(url, options: [:], completionHandler: { (result) in
                    if result {
                        NSLog("opened url")
                    } else {
                        let alertPrompt = UIAlertController(title: "Cannot open url", message: nil, preferredStyle: .alert)
                        let confirmAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: { (action) -> Void in
                        })
                        alertPrompt.addAction(confirmAction)
                        self.present(alertPrompt, animated: true, completion: {
                            self.setupCapture()
                        })
                    }
                })        
            })
            alertPrompt.addAction(confirmAction)
        }
        let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel, handler: { (action) -> Void in
            self.setupCapture()
        })
        alertPrompt.addAction(cancelAction)
        present(alertPrompt, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

}
```

Second part is the extension of our `UIViewController` subclass for `AVCaptureMetadataOutputObjectsDelegate` where we catch the captured outputs.

```
extension BarCodeScannerViewController: AVCaptureMetadataOutputObjectsDelegate {

    func metadataOutput(_ output: AVCaptureMetadataOutput, didOutput metadataObjects: [AVMetadataObject], from connection: AVCaptureConnection) {
        handleCapturedOutput(metadataObjects: metadataObjects)
    }

}
```

**Update for Swift 4.2**

`.UIApplicationWillEnterForeground`changes as `UIApplication.willEnterForegroundNotification`.

Comment: will this give the Product name, size, price, product url, currency, storename ? or it will give just the barcode number @abdullahselek

Comment: @R.Mohan it's related to barcode you read. Please check [AVCaptureMetadataOutput](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avcapturemetadataoutput) and [AVMetadataMachineReadableCodeObject](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avmetadatamachinereadablecodeobject) and try reading `metadataObjects` inside the **handleCapturedOutput** function.

Comment: Ok, will try that. Thank you for the reply @abdullahselek

Answer (score 5):

If support for the iPad 2 or iPod Touch is important for your application, I'd choose a barcode scanner SDK that can decode barcodes in blurry images, such as our [Scandit barcode scanner SDK](http://www.scandit.com) for iOS and Android. Decoding blurry barcode images is also helpful on phones with autofocus cameras because the user does not have to wait for the autofocus to kick in.

Scandit comes with a free community price plan and also has a product API that makes it easy to convert barcode numbers into product names.

(Disclaimer: I'm a co-founder of Scandit)

Answer (score 3):

The problem with iPhone camera is that the first models (of which there are tons in use) have a fixed-focus camera that cannot take picture in-focus for distances under 2ft. The images are blurry and distorted and if taken from greater distance there is not enough detail/information from the barcode.

A few companies have developed iPhone apps that can accomodate for that by using advanced de-blurring technologies. Those applications you can find on Apple app store: pic2shop, RedLaser and ShopSavvy. All of the companies have announced that they have also SDKs available - some for free or very preferential terms, check that one out.

Comment: I've tried to use ShopSavvy with a 3G iphone.  It's amusing, but crashes very frequently, and has a very, very hard time reading very clear, flat barcodes.

Comment: And I just tried pic2shop.  Quote from my fiancee: "this is supposed to make our lives easier HOW?"  It's a cute app, but it's not actually able to read a barcode as far as I can tell.

Comment: Which format did you try to read? I tried to use pic2shop to scan EAN and it works very well. The license fee is expensive though, even more than RedLaser.

Answer (score 2):

with **Swift 5** it's Simple and Super fast!!

You just need to add cocoa pods "BarcodeScanner" here is the full code

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git' 
platform :ios, '12.0' 
target 'Simple BarcodeScanner' 
do   
pod 'BarcodeScanner' 
end
```

Make sure add Camera permission in your .plist file

```
<key>NSCameraUsageDescription</key>
<string>Camera usage description</string>
```

And add Scanner and handle result in your ViewController this way

```
import UIKit
import BarcodeScanner

class ViewController: UIViewController, BarcodeScannerCodeDelegate, BarcodeScannerErrorDelegate, BarcodeScannerDismissalDelegate {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let viewController = BarcodeScannerViewController()
        viewController.codeDelegate = self
        viewController.errorDelegate = self
        viewController.dismissalDelegate = self

        present(viewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    func scanner(_ controller: BarcodeScannerViewController, didCaptureCode code: String, type: String) {
        print("Product's Bar code is :", code)
        controller.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    func scanner(_ controller: BarcodeScannerViewController, didReceiveError error: Error) {
        print(error)
    }

    func scannerDidDismiss(_ controller: BarcodeScannerViewController) {
        controller.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Still and any question or challenges, [please check sample application here with full source code](https://github.com/RamdhanChoudhary/A-Simple-iOS-App-for-Barcode-Reader-in-Swift)

Answer (score 1):

Here is simple code:

```
func scanbarcode()
{
    view.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor()
    captureSession = AVCaptureSession()

    let videoCaptureDevice = AVCaptureDevice.defaultDeviceWithMediaType(AVMediaTypeVideo)
    let videoInput: AVCaptureDeviceInput

    do {
        videoInput = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: videoCaptureDevice)
    } catch {
        return
    }

    if (captureSession.canAddInput(videoInput)) {
        captureSession.addInput(videoInput)
    } else {
        failed();
        return;
    }

    let metadataOutput = AVCaptureMetadataOutput()

    if (captureSession.canAddOutput(metadataOutput)) {
        captureSession.addOutput(metadataOutput)

        metadataOutput.setMetadataObjectsDelegate(self, queue: dispatch_get_main_queue())
        metadataOutput.metadataObjectTypes = [AVMetadataObjectTypeEAN8Code, AVMetadataObjectTypeEAN13Code, AVMetadataObjectTypePDF417Code]
    } else {
        failed()
        return
    }

    previewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: captureSession);
    previewLayer.frame = view.layer.bounds;
    previewLayer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill;
    view.layer.addSublayer(previewLayer);
    view.addSubview(closeBtn)
    view.addSubview(backimg)

    captureSession.startRunning();

}
override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

func failed() {
    let ac = UIAlertController(title: "Scanning not supported", message: "Your device does not support scanning a code from an item. Please use a device with a camera.", preferredStyle: .Alert)
    ac.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .Default, handler: nil))
    presentViewController(ac, animated: true, completion: nil)
    captureSession = nil
}

override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    if (captureSession?.running == false) {
        captureSession.startRunning();
    }
}

override func viewWillDisappear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillDisappear(animated)

    if (captureSession?.running == true) {
        captureSession.stopRunning();
    }
}

func captureOutput(captureOutput: AVCaptureOutput!, didOutputMetadataObjects metadataObjects: [AnyObject]!, fromConnection connection: AVCaptureConnection!) {
    captureSession.stopRunning()

    if let metadataObject = metadataObjects.first {
        let readableObject = metadataObject as! AVMetadataMachineReadableCodeObject;

        AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(SystemSoundID(kSystemSoundID_Vibrate))
        foundCode(readableObject.stringValue);
    }

   // dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
}

func foundCode(code: String) {
    var createAccountErrorAlert: UIAlertView = UIAlertView()
    createAccountErrorAlert.delegate = self
    createAccountErrorAlert.title = "Alert"
    createAccountErrorAlert.message = code
    createAccountErrorAlert.addButtonWithTitle("ok")
    createAccountErrorAlert.addButtonWithTitle("Retry")
    createAccountErrorAlert.show()
    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(code, forKey: "barcode")
    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()
    ItemBarcode = code
    print(code)
}

override func prefersStatusBarHidden() -> Bool {
    return true
}

override func supportedInterfaceOrientations() -> UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
    return .Portrait
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe this can be done using AVFramework, here is the sample code to do this

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation

class ViewController: UIViewController, AVCaptureMetadataOutputObjectsDelegate
{

    @IBOutlet weak var lblQRCodeResult: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var lblQRCodeLabel: UILabel!

    var objCaptureSession:AVCaptureSession?
    var objCaptureVideoPreviewLayer:AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer?
    var vwQRCode:UIView?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.configureVideoCapture()
        self.addVideoPreviewLayer()
        self.initializeQRView()
    }

    func configureVideoCapture() {
        let objCaptureDevice = AVCaptureDevice.defaultDeviceWithMediaType(AVMediaTypeVideo)
        var error:NSError?
        let objCaptureDeviceInput: AnyObject!
        do {
            objCaptureDeviceInput = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: objCaptureDevice) as AVCaptureDeviceInput

        } catch let error1 as NSError {
            error = error1
            objCaptureDeviceInput = nil
        }
        objCaptureSession = AVCaptureSession()
        objCaptureSession?.addInput(objCaptureDeviceInput as! AVCaptureInput)
        let objCaptureMetadataOutput = AVCaptureMetadataOutput()
        objCaptureSession?.addOutput(objCaptureMetadataOutput)
        objCaptureMetadataOutput.setMetadataObjectsDelegate(self, queue: dispatch_get_main_queue())
        objCaptureMetadataOutput.metadataObjectTypes = [AVMetadataObjectTypeQRCode]
    }

    func addVideoPreviewLayer() {
        objCaptureVideoPreviewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: objCaptureSession)
        objCaptureVideoPreviewLayer?.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill
        objCaptureVideoPreviewLayer?.frame = view.layer.bounds
        self.view.layer.addSublayer(objCaptureVideoPreviewLayer!)
        objCaptureSession?.startRunning()
        self.view.bringSubviewToFront(lblQRCodeResult)
        self.view.bringSubviewToFront(lblQRCodeLabel)
    }

    func initializeQRView() {
        vwQRCode = UIView()
        vwQRCode?.layer.borderColor = UIColor.redColor().CGColor
        vwQRCode?.layer.borderWidth = 5
        self.view.addSubview(vwQRCode!)
        self.view.bringSubviewToFront(vwQRCode!)
    }

    func captureOutput(captureOutput: AVCaptureOutput!, didOutputMetadataObjects metadataObjects: [AnyObject]!, fromConnection connection: AVCaptureConnection!) {
        if metadataObjects == nil || metadataObjects.count == 0 {
            vwQRCode?.frame = CGRectZero
            lblQRCodeResult.text = "QR Code wans't found"
            return
        }
        let objMetadataMachineReadableCodeObject = metadataObjects[0] as! AVMetadataMachineReadableCodeObject
        if objMetadataMachineReadableCodeObject.type == AVMetadataObjectTypeQRCode {
            let objBarCode = objCaptureVideoPreviewLayer?.transformedMetadataObjectForMetadataObject(objMetadataMachineReadableCodeObject as AVMetadataMachineReadableCodeObject) as! AVMetadataMachineReadableCodeObject
            vwQRCode?.frame = objBarCode.bounds;
            if objMetadataMachineReadableCodeObject.stringValue != nil {
                lblQRCodeResult.text = objMetadataMachineReadableCodeObject.stringValue
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are developing for iOS >10.2 with Swift 4 then you can try my solution. I mixed up [this](https://www.appcoda.com/qr-code-reader-swift/) and [this](https://www.appcoda.com/barcode-reader-swift/) tutorial and came up with a ViewController which scans a QR Code and `print()` it out. I also have a Switch in my UI to toggle the camera light, might be helpful as well. For now I only tested it on a iPhone SE, please let me know if it doesn't work on newer iPhones.

Here you go:

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation

class QRCodeScanner: UIViewController, AVCaptureMetadataOutputObjectsDelegate {

    let captureSession: AVCaptureSession = AVCaptureSession()
    var videoPreviewLayer: AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer?
    let qrCodeFrameView: UIView = UIView()
    var captureDevice: AVCaptureDevice?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        // Get the back-facing camera for capturing videos
        let deviceDiscoverySession = AVCaptureDevice.DiscoverySession(deviceTypes: [.builtInWideAngleCamera, .builtInDualCamera], mediaType: AVMediaType.video, position: .back)

        captureDevice = deviceDiscoverySession.devices.first
        if captureDevice == nil {
            print("Failed to get the camera device")
            return
        }

        do {
            // Get an instance of the AVCaptureDeviceInput class using the previous device object.
            let input = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: captureDevice!)

            // Set the input device on the capture session.
            captureSession.addInput(input)

            // Initialize a AVCaptureMetadataOutput object and set it as the output device to the capture session.
            let captureMetadataOutput = AVCaptureMetadataOutput()
            captureSession.addOutput(captureMetadataOutput)

            // Set delegate and use the default dispatch queue to execute the call back
            captureMetadataOutput.setMetadataObjectsDelegate(self, queue: DispatchQueue.main)
            captureMetadataOutput.metadataObjectTypes = [AVMetadataObject.ObjectType.qr]

            // Initialize the video preview layer and add it as a sublayer to the viewPreview view's layer.

            videoPreviewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: captureSession)

            if let videoPreviewLayer = videoPreviewLayer {
                videoPreviewLayer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravity.resizeAspectFill
                videoPreviewLayer.frame = view.layer.bounds
                view.layer.addSublayer(videoPreviewLayer)

                // Start video capture.
                captureSession.startRunning()

                if let hasFlash = captureDevice?.hasFlash, let hasTorch = captureDevice?.hasTorch {
                    if hasFlash && hasTorch {
                        view.bringSubview(toFront: bottomBar)
                        try captureDevice?.lockForConfiguration()
                    }
                }
            }

            // QR Code Overlay
            qrCodeFrameView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.green.cgColor
            qrCodeFrameView.layer.borderWidth = 2
            view.addSubview(qrCodeFrameView)
            view.bringSubview(toFront: qrCodeFrameView)

        } catch {
            // If any error occurs, simply print it out and don't continue any more.
            print("Error: \(error)")
            return
        }
    }

    // MARK: Buttons and Switch

    @IBAction func switchFlashChanged(_ sender: UISwitch) {
        do {
            if sender.isOn {
                captureDevice?.torchMode = .on
            } else {
                captureDevice?.torchMode = .off
            }
        }
    }

    // MARK: AVCaptureMetadataOutputObjectsDelegate

    func metadataOutput(_ output: AVCaptureMetadataOutput, didOutput metadataObjects: [AVMetadataObject], from connection: AVCaptureConnection) {

        // Check if the metadataObjects array is not nil and it contains at least one object.
        if metadataObjects.count == 0 {
            qrCodeFrameView.frame = CGRect.zero
            return
        }

        // Get the metadata object.
        let metadataObj = metadataObjects[0] as! AVMetadataMachineReadableCodeObject

        if metadataObj.type == AVMetadataObject.ObjectType.qr {
            // If the found metadata is equal to the QR code metadata then update the status label's text and set the bounds
            let barCodeObject = videoPreviewLayer?.transformedMetadataObject(for: metadataObj)
            qrCodeFrameView.frame = barCodeObject!.bounds

            print("QR Code: \(metadataObj.stringValue)")
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can check  ZBarSDK  to reads QR Code and ECN/ISBN codes it's simple to integrate try the following code.

```
- (void)scanBarcodeWithZBarScanner
  {
// ADD: present a barcode reader that scans from the camera feed
ZBarReaderViewController *reader = [ZBarReaderViewController new];
reader.readerDelegate = self;
reader.supportedOrientationsMask = ZBarOrientationMaskAll;

ZBarImageScanner *scanner = reader.scanner;
// TODO: (optional) additional reader configuration here

// EXAMPLE: disable rarely used I2/5 to improve performance
 [scanner setSymbology: ZBAR_I25
               config: ZBAR_CFG_ENABLE
                   to: 0];

//Get the return value from controller
[reader setReturnBlock:^(BOOL value) {

}
```

and in didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo we get bar code value.

```
    - (void) imagePickerController: (UIImagePickerController*) reader
   didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo: (NSDictionary*) info
   {
    // ADD: get the decode results
    id<NSFastEnumeration> results =
    [info objectForKey: ZBarReaderControllerResults];
    ZBarSymbol *symbol = nil;
    for(symbol in results)
    // EXAMPLE: just grab the first barcode
    break;

    // EXAMPLE: do something useful with the barcode data
    barcodeValue = symbol.data;

    // EXAMPLE: do something useful with the barcode image
    barcodeImage =   [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
    [_barcodeIV setImage:barcodeImage];

    //set the values for to TextFields
    [self setBarcodeValue:YES];

    // ADD: dismiss the controller (NB dismiss from the *reader*!)
    [reader dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is to use 3rd party framework with minimum UI that can be improved. Check [QRCodeScanner83](https://github.com/seriyvolk83/QRCodeScanner)

You can simply use the following code (check the documentation on how to create view controller in your storyboard):

```swift
import QRCodeScanner83

guard let vc = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(identifier: "CodeScannerViewController") as? CodeScannerViewController else {
    return
}
vc.callbackCodeScanned = { code in
    print("SCANNED CODE: \(code)")
    vc.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
self.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
```