# iPhone simple commercial barcode reader via camera

Tags: iphone, barcode

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a barcode recognition framework for iOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/838724/is-there-a-barcode-recognition-framework-for-ios)

I've done some iPhone programming (safely midlevel) and now a requirement has come up for us to write a barcode reader that uses the iPhone camera. This is not for shopping or the general public but will be for internal use. My first thought was to simply programatically take a picture, upload it to server, and have a web service or something similar handle the heavy lifting of extracting the numbers out of the bar code. However I recently installed some apps already available on the iPhone that read bar codes, refer you to shopping sites, etc. and they seem to use the video camera to identify barcodes and extract the numbers. Does anyone know how this is being done or could point me to some open source or sample code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This looks helpful:

http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/zbar/index.php?title=HOWTO:_Add_a_barcode_reader_to_an_iPhone_app