# how to decode EAN-13 barcode image in iPhone?

Tags: objective-c, ios4, barcode, decoding

In my application , i need to decode EAN-13 barcode image.The image captured from a iphone camera.after capturing barcode image i have to decode .i am new to iphone.

please refer me some solution or tutorial?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: See this question:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/838724/barcode-framework-for-the-iphone

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at the [ZBar SDK](http://zbar.sourceforge.net/iphone/index.html)