# BarCode Reader iphone Application

Tags: iphone

I want to create a bar code reader application in iphone. What to do to implement this functionality in my application. Please,Give the detail process.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a barcode recognition framework for iOS?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/838724/is-there-a-barcode-recognition-framework-for-ios)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can **[pay RedLaser to use their SDK](http://redlaser.com/SDK.aspx)**.

There's also the open source **[ZBar iPhone SDK](http://zbar.sourceforge.net/iphone/index.html)**.

Comment: I've had some experience with Red Laser and wanted to note that the framework works very well. Provided you can come up with a way to cover the licensing fee I'd strongly recommend using it.