# I want a barcode reader in my app

Tags: iphone, barcode

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a barcode recognition framework for iOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/838724/is-there-a-barcode-recognition-framework-for-ios)

i want to develop a bar code reader for my app ,but I dnt know where to start please help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you looked at [Redlaser](http://redlaser.com/) or [zbar](http://zbar.sourceforge.net/)?

Answer (score 2):

You could use ZXing. See the accepted answer from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/838724/barcode-framework-for-the-iphone) question