# QR code reader for iPhone

Tags: iphone, qr-code, zxing

I want to create QR code reader based application.

Using which library, I can create my application ?

**Note:** I searched in google. Always I am getting **zxing**. I downloaded the zxing project. But the problem is; I run the application. But it is reading only the **Barcodes**. There is no option to read QR code.

Please tell me how to do this...

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/838724/barcode-framework-for-the-iphone/862656#862656 this answer links to source for barcode app which reads qrcodes. You should get some good info there

Comment: zxing definitely does QR codes on iOS very well. Better, in fact, than it does other codes. The sample ScanTest app demonstrates how it is used and will decode QR codes well.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

[ZBarSDK](http://zbar.sourceforge.net/iphone/index.html) is another option. A very capable library.

**UPDATE** January 2014

Beginning in iOS7, `AVCaptureDevice` now includes the ability to read barcodes (of all kinds) and return a human readable value. If you're targeting iOS7+, this is the way to go. ZBarSDK is still great for pre-iOS7 support, of course.

Comment: I haven't released anything using it, but as far as I have tested, a reliable library, also offers quite a nice module for capture (for example highlights the code and so on) and quite easy to understand.

Comment: ZBarSDK is free license version ? Can I use ZBarSDK for my paid app ?

Comment: Please note that ZBarSDK license requires you to provide the source code upon request

Answer (score 29):

`AVCaptureMetaDataOutput` - Starting from iOS 7

Scan UPCs, QR codes, and barcodes of all varieties with AVCaptureMetaDataOutput, new to iOS 7. All you need to do is set it up as the output of an `AVCaptureSession`, and implement the `captureOutput:didOutputMetadataObjects:fromConnection:` method accordingly:

```
 @import AVFoundation;

 AVCaptureSession *session = [[AVCaptureSession alloc] init];
 AVCaptureDevice *device = [AVCaptureDevice defaultDeviceWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];
 NSError *error = nil;

 AVCaptureDeviceInput *input = [AVCaptureDeviceInput deviceInputWithDevice:device
                                                                error:&error];
 if (input) {
     [session addInput:input];
 } else {
     NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
 }

 AVCaptureMetadataOutput *output = [[AVCaptureMetadataOutput alloc] init];
 [output setMetadataObjectTypes:@[AVMetadataObjectTypeQRCode]];
 [output setMetadataObjectsDelegate:self queue:dispatch_get_main_queue()];
 [session addOutput:output];

 [session startRunning];

 #pragma mark - AVCaptureMetadataOutputObjectsDelegate

 - (void)captureOutput:(AVCaptureOutput *)captureOutput
         didOutputMetadataObjects:(NSArray *)metadataObjects
              fromConnection:(AVCaptureConnection *)connection
   {
    NSString *QRCode = nil;
     for (AVMetadataObject *metadata in metadataObjects) {
       if ([metadata.type isEqualToString:AVMetadataObjectTypeQRCode]) {
            // This will never happen; nobody has ever scanned a QR code... ever
             QRCode = [(AVMetadataMachineReadableCodeObject *)metadata stringValue];
             break;
          }
      }

     NSLog(@"QR Code: %@", QRCode);
   }
```

`AVFoundation` supports every code you've heard of (and probably a few that you haven't):

```
AVMetadataObjectTypeUPCECode
AVMetadataObjectTypeCode39Code
AVMetadataObjectTypeCode39Mod43Code
AVMetadataObjectTypeEAN13Code
AVMetadataObjectTypeEAN8Code
AVMetadataObjectTypeCode93Code
AVMetadataObjectTypeCode128Code
AVMetadataObjectTypePDF417Code
AVMetadataObjectTypeQRCode
AVMetadataObjectTypeAztecCode
```

Comment: This saved me tons and tons of hassle, would have started integrated the old SDKs... also this is a good read: http://www.renaudpradenc.com/?p=453

Comment: I wish I could +1 this twice. Once for the code, and another for the use of `@import`.

Comment: For a more complete example that also handles things like orientation changes, resuming from background and such, see https://github.com/magmatic/BMCodeScanner - uses native AVFoundation API.

Comment: `[session addOutput:]` method must be called before `[output setMetadataObjectTypes:@AVMetadataObjectTypeQRCode]];`. Otherwise you'll get an NSInvalidArgumentException.

Comment: thanks @SebastianZ I was getting errors constantly because of this

Answer (score 3):

Try [ZXingObjC](https://github.com/TheLevelUp/ZXingObjC) working great and easy to integrate.

As well, you can define the size of the scanner window inside your view.

Answer (score -1):

for your reference  you can use **webqr.com** and it's library you can use for decode the QR code and encoding also . But for different browser like safari, Chrome, IE, Firefox, you can add the plugin for This. Hope so it will help full for you.