# What are the Frameworks used for QR code reader application

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios5

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [QR code reader for iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5902705/qr-code-reader-for-iphone)
>   [QR Code library for iphone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6120071/qr-code-library-for-iphone)

I want to develop an application for QR code reader.So i need to know what are the frameworks that i need to implement for this application.

Answer (score 1):

I had some success integrating zbar into an OS X app.

http://zbar.sourceforge.net/index.html

It also has support for iOS and a sample app you can use it with.

Answer (score 0):

This is the only open-source project I know of that has anything to do with QR codes on iOS, but it looks like it should work for you: Zebra Crossing ( http://code.google.com/p/zxing/ ).

Answer (score 0):

You can find a similar question here : 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6120071/qr-code-library-for-iphone

than i suggest this: http://redlaser.com/