# Are there any iOS frameworks that can do barcode recognition using fixed focus cameras?

Tags: iphone, ios, barcode

I'm aware of the many available barcode recognition frameworks for iOS listed in response to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/838724/is-there-a-barcode-recognition-framework-for-ios), but none of those seem to work with fixed focus cameras, like those on older iPhones and the newer iPod touches.

Are there any frameworks out there that can do barcode recognition using a fixed-focus camera, or is there a way to get these existing frameworks to support these devices?

Answer (score -1):

Other options (in additions to Benoit's) are:

- [RedLaser](http://redlaser.com/) by eBay
- [Scandit](http://www.scandit.com/) by Mirasense

Both support fixed focus devices, several operating systems and have free apps to test them.

And both want to approve your app before you upload it to the App Store, both phone home and transmit every scanned barcode together with some undocumented additional information.