# How can I use barcode reader in iPhone (iOS 5)?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ios5, barcode-scanner

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a barcode recognition framework for iOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/838724/is-there-a-barcode-recognition-framework-for-ios)

I have a project on iPhone using iOS 5. I have to make an attandance system using bar code scanning and the bar code reader will be the iPhone device itself. Does anybody have any idea from where I should start?

Answer (score 0):

I have integrated ZBar SDK for iOS 5. So, You can easily integrate.

Comment: is it scanning QR codes correctly on ios 5 ? Zbar is working fine for ios versions<5 but not doing good for ios5 :(