# 1D barcode Scanner IOS (Xcode)

Tags: ios, xcode, barcode, scanning

I was wondering if there was a Xcode project out there that could scan 1D barcodes as I need a 1D barcode scanner in my app I am making and don't know how to do it

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: please evaluate simular QAs (referenced at the side-bar)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could take a look at: [ZBar](http://zbar.sourceforge.net/index.html)

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks dude this look like it will work, I will have to try it tomrow when I get up!

Answer (score 0):

There is barcode/ QR Code reader library [ZXing](http://code.google.com/p/zxing/), which I believe is from google. Also they have an [example project](http://code.google.com/p/zxing/source/browse/trunk#trunk/iphone/ScanTest) to show how to integrate ZXing on your iphone project.

EDIT : sorry, zxing currently only supports QR codes for iphone as indicated [here](http://code.google.com/p/zxing/).

> iphone: iPhone client + port to Objective C / C++ (QR code only)

But it seems it can be ported to iphone, as its developer says it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/838724/is-there-a-barcode-recognition-framework-for-ios). Also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5659380/free-barcode-scanner-sdk-for-ios-iphone) thread might interest you. Especially the comments under highest voted answer.

Comment: Yea but I think zxing only let's you use QR codes not 1D codes for IOS, is that right?