# iOS library for Barcode reader

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ipad

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a barcode recognition framework for iOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/838724/is-there-a-barcode-recognition-framework-for-ios)

Which is the best free sdk or library for iOS barcode reader? i am currently implementing an app for my company and we want to support barcode and QR code scan, can someone please suggest me the best sdk that works on iOS4,5 ?

Answer (score 23):

I would suggest you, have a look on below some good API for bar code scanning

**Update on May-2019**

- [ZXing](http://code.google.com/p/zxing/) (*Now only available for Android*)
- [ZBar bar code reader](http://zbar.sourceforge.net/)
- [shopsavvy](http://shopsavvy.mobi/developers/)
- [Softek Barcode Reader SDK](http://www.bardecode.com/en1/app/mobilesdk/)
- [Scandit Barcode Scanner](http://docs.scandit.com/stable/ios/) (not free)

Here is the code snip if you use ZBar API

```
ZBarReaderController *reader = [ZBarReaderController new];
reader.readerDelegate = self;

    //... code to get image

CGImageRef imgCG = image.CGImage;


id<NSFastEnumeration> results = [reader scanImage:imgCG];
ZBarSymbol *symbol = nil;

for(symbol in results)
    // EXAMPLE: just grab the first barcode
    break;
resultText.text = symbol.data;
```

Also Make sure PL don't forget to use weak link for AVFoundation, CoreVideo and CoreMedia framework

Comment: For the sake of completeness, this should be mentioned:
http://docs.scandit.com/stable/ios/

Comment: @mindbomb thank you for the suggestion, updated answer with **Scandid lib**

Comment: ZXing is currently only for Android

Comment: @Nativ thank you for you suggestion, updated!!

Comment: Nowadays the most important APIs are probably the built-in ones. iOS: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/vision?language=objc and Android: https://developers.google.com/vision/android/barcodes-overview

Comment: For completeness, this one was the very first available for iOS (before RedLaser for those old enough to remember - and still available): https://www.visionsmarts.com/index.html#products

Answer (score 7):

The ZBAR iPhone sdk is very much effective for reading bar codes and qrcodes. You can find the sdk files and how to use the sdk tutorials in [here](http://zbar.sourceforge.net/iphone/sdkdoc/)